# Як правильно "надсилати на адресу" чи "надсилати за адресою"?

Tags: вживання-слів

Мене цікавить чи можливе вживання обох варіантів? 
Чи все таки один є лише правильним.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильним є лише один варіант ***надсилати на адресу***

На запитання куди? відповідає в цьому випадку іменник із прийменником *на*, який означає напрямок дії. Листи *надсилайте на адресу*... По довідки *звертайтеся на адресу...* 
Підтвердження цьому можемо знайти  в [Довіднику "Правильно-Неправильно" М.Волощак](http://nepravylno-pravylno.wikidot.com/all)

Answer (score 2):

До [відповіді Марії Мацкевич](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/3158) хотів би додати, що…

## Не кожен ужиток форми «за адресою» є неправильним

Зацитую [«Уроки державної мови» Бориса Рогози з газети «Хрещатик»](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53405/26061.html):

> Багато рекламних текстів, що їх уміщують наші ЗМІ, закінчуються синтаксично безграмотним закликом звертатися за адресою. На запитання ***куди?*** відповідає в цьому випадку іменник із прийменником ***на***, який означає напрямок дії. *Листи надсилайте **на адресу**… По довідки звертайтеся **на адресу**…*
>
> ***За*** вживаємо тоді, коли треба вказати **місце, де відбувається дія**. *Курси для вивчення іноземних мов розташовані **за адресою**…*

Тобто не рекомендується застосування прийменника *за* лише в тому випадку, коли мова про місце призначення; коли ж мова про місце події, *за* — цілком прийнятний прийменник.

Наприклад:

> Центральне відділення пошти знаходилося **за адресою**: вул. Хрещатик, 22. Прийшовши туди, я довго не міг вкумекати, в яке саме мені віконце звертатися і як саме заповнювати бланк, але врешті-решт спромігся надіслати листа своєму товаришу **на адресу**: вул. Дмитрова, 2, м. Львів.

## Змішалося все…

Форму «за адресою» настільки часто вживають при зазначенні місця призначення, що вона уже потрапила у сучасний тлумачний «Словник української мови» в 20 томах (2010-і роки), хоч і поки що лише опосередковано:

> [**АДРЕ́СА**](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=519&page=22), и, *ж[іночий рід]*. <…>
>
> **△ (2) Адре́са електро́нної по́шти <Електро́нна адре́са>**, *інформ[атика]*  <…>. *Редакція газети просить надсилати відгуки за поштовою адресою **[!]** або за електронною адресою **[!]**, яка вказана на веб-сторінці газети* (з мови реклами); <…>
>
> ◇ **(4) Не за адре́сою *[!]***, *перев[ажно] зі сл[овом] звертатися* — не до того, до кого треба; не туди, куди слід. *Продавець тільки плечима стенула: мовляв, не за адресою звертаються* (із журн.) <…>
>
> <sub>(Виділення знаком ***[!]*** моє.)</sub>

Тобто вираз «за адресою» у значенні «куди?» вже потрапив у тлумачний словник всередині прикладів, а вираз «не за адресою» у значенні «не туди» явно зафіксовано. Можливо, справа йде до унормування виразу «за адресою» при зазначенні місця призначення?

## Мої особисті асоціації

Частіше ми кажемо «розмовляю **українською мовою**», аніж «розмовляю **на українській мові**». Однак у випадку перекладу справа не така однозначна — ми цілком можемо сказати: «перекладаю з англійської **на українську**» (я спеціально перевіряв — така форма вживається, зокрема в класиків) — адже йдеться про цільову мову / мову призначення. Одначе зараз і вираз «перекладаю **українською** (з іноземної)» є цілком вживаним (дехто навіть лише його сприймає як питомий, хоч це не так) — тобто відбулося зміщення акцентів і ми при зазначенні цільового місця/стану застосовуємо форму, використовувану при зазначенні поточного місця/стану.

Можливо, схожі явища відбуваються і у випадку адреси. Теоретично, використання форми «за адресою» під час заповнення конверту / прокладання маршруту можна було б спробувати обґрунтувати пунктами 11–12 статті «за¹» в тому ж словнику:

> [**ЗА¹**](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=27400&page=918) <…>
>
> 11. *з оруд[ним] і знах[ним] в[ідмінком]* Уживається на означення способу дії. <…>
> 12. *з оруд[ним] в[ідмінком]*. Уживається при вказуванні на те, згідно з чим, відповідно до чого відбувається дія. <…>

Хоч це й значною мірою притягнуто за вуха.

Єдине, що, на мою думку, суттєво відрізняє мову і адресу в їх співвідношенні з аспектами поточного стану/місця та цільового стану/місця — це те, що мову при зазначенні поточного стану/місця не приєднують сполучником «за», достатньо лише орудного відмінку, а у випадку адреси… Хоча… О, ти ба:

> Питанняі пропозиції **надсилайте адресою** - приховано@gmail.com (з YouTube).
>   Сценірій євро-казок про вікінгів **надсилайте адресою** в Лосанджелес! (з WikiVisually).

Може, скоро й така форма прийде спочатку в розмовний стиль, а потім і в норму.